# What image libraries have been ported to the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, image

I am researching iPhone image libraries. I am looking for a lightweight image library that will compile on an iPhone.  Have any libraries such as ImageMagick been ported?  What image libraries would be best suited for the iPhone?

The image library should be suited to do black & white, sepia tone, saturation filters, and more sophisticated effects such as oil painting, etc.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But Core Graphic won't do any of image filtering mention above. That's a part of Core Image, which is apparently missing from iPhone SDK.

Answer (score 2):

The iPhone SDK comes with a very good image library, Core Graphics.  From the SDK Documentation:

> The Core Graphics framework is a
>   C-based API that provides low-level,
>   lightweight 2D rendering with superb
>   output fidelity. Use this framework,
>   which is based on the Quartz drawing
>   engine, for path-based drawing,
>   anti-aliased rendering, gradients,
>   images, color management,
>   coordinate-space transformations, and
>   PDF document handling.

Check Out: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/Topics/GraphicsAnimation/index.html

And :http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/Frameworks/Media/CoreGraphics/index.html

(Login required for both).

Comment: I am not that familiar with Core Graphics. Could it be used to generate image filters, such as an oil painting effect?

Comment: CoreGraphics on iPhone has no filters and cannot do the requested "...sepia tone, saturation filters, and more sophisticated effects such as oil painting"

I'm not aware of any libraries ported to iPhone that can perform those effects.

Comment: That is what I had read in the API docs.  Core Graphics is not the answer then.

Comment: Sorry about the recommendation.  The only way to do it with Core Graphics would be to roll your own processing using a CGBitmapContext and iterate through the pixels.  It looks like some people have tried to compile ImageMajick for the iPhone without any success.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there has been some success porting ImageMagick it to iOS:

http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=14089